# Json.net Deserializing strings containing lists

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a web service returning me this output. I am trying to deserialize the output in C# and json.net

```
[{"UserName":"domain\\user1","UserRoles":[{"RoleName":"admin"}]},{"UserName":"domain\\user2","UserRoles":[{"RoleName":"crsuser"}]},{"UserName":"domain\\user3","UserRoles":[{"RoleName":"admin"}]}]
```

I can parse this output and then I can put this into a JArray Object and iterate over it.
Now in each iterating I want to take the string and desialize the string into this object

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public List<Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="RoleName")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how to handle the List. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? I can't see a reason why the list wouldn't deserialize.. can you show us your code?

Comment: I can deserialize Role class easily. but I cannot deserialize user class because it contains an array. and I have no attribute on top of the array (for non-array attributes I have JsonProperty).

Comment: ...can you show us the code you've tried to use to deserialize User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I solved the problem. here is the deserialize of the User object

```
        List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(rawData);
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);
            foreach (Role role in user.UserRoles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(role.RoleName);
            }
        }
```